# Apache and Tomcat proxying

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, configuration

Recently, I was in need of using both Apache and Tomcat together in which Apache was to be used as the reverse proxy to forward requests to port 80 to localhost:8080 which I did like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
        ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/app/
</VirtualHost>
```

And it works perfectly well.

Now, what I need to do is: I have Tomcat listening and serving on another port 8082. I need to be able to access it using www.mydomain.com:8082. I tried:

```
<VirtualHost *:8082>
        ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8082/app/
</VirtualHost>
```

But no luck. And I can't listen on 8082 because Tomcat is doing that.

Answer (score 2):

What you have above is a (failed) attempt to map the `/` URL space into two different places. That's never going to work.

When proxying to Tomcat, it's never a good idea to rewrite URL paths (e.g. `/` -> `/app/` because Tomcat is going to get all kinds of confused. It's much better to map individual applications:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
  ProxyPass /app1/ http://localhost:8080/app1/
  ProxyPass /app2/ http://localhost:8080/app2/
  ProxyPass /app3/ http://localhost:8082/app3/
  ProxyPass /app4/ http://localhost:8082/app4/
  # If you need a fall-back application for `/`, just map it last.
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that the last line up there is mapping `/` to Tomcat's `ROOT` context (mounted on `/`'). Don't do this any other way, or you'll spend years trying to make everything work when you could have just done it the recommended way.